# Allowing certain file types in php

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to allow users to upload images to my website. The current php code I am using always gives an error that the file type uploaded is invalid. I have tried tons of images and they all give this error.

Here is the php code.

```
<?php
   // Configuration - Your Options
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png','.jpeg'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
      //$max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
      $upload_path = 'uploads'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   // Upload the file to your specified path.
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
      else
         echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

?>
```

Here is the HTML Form code.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>
      <label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"> <br />
      <button>Upload File</button>
   <p>
</form>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't seem to have a submit button

Comment: Bad code. you assume the upload succeeded. you assume the uploader hasn't forged the filename (e.g. `ren nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.jpg`), do size checks which should have been enforced at the server level to begin with, and are allowing users to specify paths **AND** filenames, potentially allowing them to scribble on ANY directory on your server.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with this code, which include that the code to get a file extension does not work correctly in the general case. Replace it with this, it should also solve your current issue:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowed_filetypes = array('jpg','gif','bmp','png','jpeg');
```

You should also definitely heed the warnings of [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146406/allowing-certain-file-types-in-php/15146488#comment21324329_15146406) above.

Comment: Changing to these I still get the error when uploading files.

Comment: @WillGilstrap: Well, what's the value of `$ext`?

Comment: I have no idea. I am very very basic with PHP.